# Woocommerce: code for adding custom alt and title tag to product images works, but brakes product admin page

Tags: image, woocommerce, tags, fatal-error, alt

setting up a Woocommerce shop, I wanted to add custom alt and title tags to product images, based on product title, tags and one attribute. I added code to child functions.php, and it seemed to work - both on front and in Media manager I got the alt and title tags I wanted, everything seemed ok.

Until I tried to edit a product page on the admin area....it loads only halfway (the whole section below the main content box is missing), shows no product tags added, and by the product image it says :

**Fatal error: Call to a member function get_tags() on null in functions.php on line 112**

My code in the child functions.php ($authortags beeing line 112):

```
// Change images alt and title tag 
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2);
function change_attachement_image_attributes($attr, $attachment) {
global $post, $product;
if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $authortags = strip_tags ($product->get_tags());
    $editor = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_szerkesztette' );

    $attr['alt'] = $title .' '. $authortags .' '. $editor;
    $attr['title'] = $title .' '. $authortags .' '. $editor;
}
return $attr;
}
```

It's the same with all product pages. I guess the problem is stripping the tags, and I should find another method to get them in the code, but nothing I've tried did work (my php knowledge is rather limited...) .

Could anyone help me, what am I doing wrong, how to modify the code to get this work?
Thanks

Comment: I think you're using $product instead of $post.

Comment: "Call to a member function get_tags() on null" signals that problem is `$product` is not a product object, but rather is a null variable. You can't assume that `$product` is always globally set. It would be better to get the product from the post ID. `$product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );`

Comment: Big thanks to both of you, changed the code as helgatheviking suggested and it's working.

Comment: Could you submit and then accept your new code as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@helgatheviking I spent yesterday cca. 10 minutes trying to find out how to accept your suggestion as an answer until I realized a comment is technically not an answer...learning to use stackoverflow.

Here is the working code:

```
// Change images alt and title tag 
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2);
function change_attachement_image_attributes($attr, $attachment) {
global $post;
$product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $authortags = strip_tags ($product->get_tags());
    $editor = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_szerkesztette' );

    $attr['alt'] = $title .' '. $authortags .' '. $editor;
    $attr['title'] = $title .' '. $authortags .' '. $editor;
    }
    return $attr;
}
```